# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I want to call this function in my button. But every time I click the button it always shows error

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property
>   or method

I think the trouble happens because I'm not put jquery.js in my code, but after I put jquery.js, it always conflicts with the DropDown.js. I already tried to use jQuery.noConflict(); but it doesn't work too.
Thank you in advance.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/DropDown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/Common.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/DropDown.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/Common.js"></script>   
    <script type = "text/javascript">

           function cekData() {
               var periode;
               periode = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTglAwal').value;
               $.ajax({
                   type: "post",
                   url: "AjaxToolkit.asmx/CekPeriodeData",
                   data: '{ tgl: "' + periode + '" }',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (r) {
                       alert(r.d);

                   },
                   failure: function (xhr, status, error) {

                       alert('Error');
                   }
               });
           }

        </script>
```

Comment: change `failure` to `error`

Comment: Still get this error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method @plonknimbuzz

Comment: You listed several scripts but not jquery. you think there is a conflict? add jquery first and remove dropdown.js and see if there's a problem.